# opencv contour template match

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, contour

The goal is to find the position of certain objects in some images, these objects have similar shape, but totally different colour, and a little bit different on size. The shape is known, so template with a reasonable similarity can be created if necessary.

I know opencv has shape matching function which can return matching result in double, but cannot give a best matching position, i.e. the object position in the image. I can cut the image into sections and run matching shape on each, but the problem is, the size of that object is not previously known, therefore, to do it in this way, different section sizes should all be tried.

So I am wondering if there is other more manageable method to do this?Like the match template method, except for a contour instead of a solid picture section. BTW, I tried to do some preporcess to get rid of noise inside the object so it becomes a section with contour only, and the template matching can be applied, but it is not working, always noise inside.

Any suggestion on this issue? Thanks.

Comment: THe question reads, as if you have interesting code to show, and based on that people will for sure offer advice. Could you put somethin into the question? That would be great.

Comment: @Dilettant This is not a coding issue, currently. It's just seeking for some methods. The code is nothing more than imread, matchShapes (which is not even working).

Comment: if it not a coding issue then it is off topic

Comment: @FirstStep It's programming related, but not on a directly code related level issue yet, I assume it is safe to post such question here?

Comment: Without some example images it's difficult to say something definite. The method of choice will definitely depend on the data.